# Getting Error msg Unsafe attempt to load URL when I try to click and open an xml link from webpage

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have an application that has some links in the form of .xml . When you click on them they should open. In IE this is working fine but in chrome I'm getting some error message as shown in the screen shot. I have tried a couple of solution like (chrome.exe --disable-web-security) to resolve this but nothing worked. If Anyone can help i will really appreciated 
[image]

Comment: i just tagged chrome extension thinking there might be a plugin that can help with this. Sorry!

Comment: Looks like this is intentional, https://crbug.com/70088